# What is a word for someone whose emotions are not hurt easily?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone whose emotions are not hurt easily? I'm looking for something more specific than 'robust' and 'stable'.

Comment: I'm surprised that this kind of questions are allowed. You need to provide a context. At the minimum a full sentence more descriptive than "he is robust/stable/stoic/thick-skinned/etc.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment, I'm new on this part of SE, just followed the most common formatting I saw from google searches that brought me here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example:

"thick-skinned"
adjective
insensitive to criticism or insults.

Answer (score 15):

How about **stoic**? It tends to mean "unemotional", but it can certainly describe lack of emotional response to criticism, insults, etc.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains an explanation of why it is correct.
Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
Do not answer questions which are unclear, out of scope, or already answered many times before. The question lacks evidence of research.
Word or phrase requests must be expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 5):

What about **imperturbable**?

> adjective: unable to be upset or excited; calm.

or **phlegmatic**

> adjective: having an unemotional and stolidly calm disposition; not easily upset, excited, or angered

or **stolid**

> adjective: showing little or no emotion : not easily excited or upset

Answer (score 4):

[**Insensitive**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insensitive) could work, but unfortunately it has two separate meanings, so could cause confusion if it's not clear which one is meant:

> - not feeling or showing sympathy for other people's feelings, or refusing to give importance to something
> - **not showing any reaction to something, or unable to feel something**

A better word might be [**thick-skinned**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thick-skinned):

> Someone who is thick-skinned does not appear to be easily hurt by criticism

Or if it doesn't have to be a single word, you could try a phrase like "**immune to criticism**" or "**hard to offend**".

Comment: unoffendable? it's a new one, would people get it?

Comment: Insensitive tends to be used to mean that the person in question **will tend to offend other people without realising/caring**, rather than being about their own feelings.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, I mentioned both meanings in my answer and that this could cause confusion, which is why I also included another, probably better, possibility.